# Statelessness in Rest

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am  reading a book on Rest architecture and came across this portion

> In particular, the application must be separated into a client-server model and the server must remain completely stateless. No client context may be stored on the server and resources should also be uniquely and uniformly identified.

1 . what does it mean for the server to remain completely stateless?

2 . No client context may be stored on the server? what client context?

Any help in breaking this down is appreciated.

Comment: You need to be much more specific. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: I wrote them in points 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does it mean for the server to remain completely stateless?

It means that every message sent to the server is considered complete of itself; the server should not be "remembering" previous messages from the client.

Consider shopping for a book.

```
Client: What's the price of [Rest in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Archicture]
Server: The price of [Rest in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Archicture] is 36.16 USD.
Client: Buy it.
```

For the server to know what "it" means, it must be remembering the previous conversation about the price of the book, to know which book the client is talking about.

Stateless means that the client never talks in pronouns

The stateless version looks like

```
Client: Buy [Rest in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Archicture].
```

Everything the server needs to know about the current state of the client is included in the message.  Maybe this client asked the price first, maybe it didn't.  It doesn't matter, because all of the information is here, in this message.

Consider this sequence:

```
Client: What's the price of [Rest in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Archicture]
Server: The price of [Rest in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Archicture] is 36.16 USD.
Client: What's the price of [Royal Oak Tourbillon]
Server: The price of [Royal Oak Tourbillon] is 122000.00 USD.
Client: Buy it.
```

Did you just buy a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829), or a [wrist watch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TU78EXE)?  The server doesn't know if you hit the back button or not.